# memory pool running on O(1)

Tags: c++, memory-management

is there a way to design a C++ memory pool (for a specific class only) that can allocate and free memory in O(1)?

let's say I have class T, I was thinking of allocating only chunks of 100*sizeof(T) when needed. But then how can I deal with the fragmentation that occurs when a specific object is deleted in the chunk? I can have a boolean value for each slot to tell if the slot is occupied or not, but then I need an algorithm to give me the next free slot.

Is there any standard way to implement this in O(1)? I guess this is a fairly common thing

edit :
image to see what I mean
[image: pic]

Comment: I don't see how that could help me... maybe my question wasn't clear?

Comment: You want something like a [free list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_list).

Comment: Maybe [Simple Segregated Storage](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/libs/pool/doc/html/boost_pool/pool/pooling.html) could be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solution is using additional memory (which may or may not be what you want), also you'll have problems if you try to free a chunk twice in a row.

Preallocate enough memory. Divide it into chunks, one per object. Keep a list of free chunks. When you allocate a new object, pick a chunk from the top of the free chunks list. When you free an object, append its chunk to the list of free chunks. Both of these operations are O(1).

It would look something like this:

Init:

```
char* mem = new char[CHUNK_SIZE * OBJ_COUNT];
std::list<char*> free_chunks;
for (char* c = mem, int i = 0; i < OBJ_COUNT; ++i)
{
   free_chunks.push_back(c);
   c += CHUNK_SIZE;
}
```

Getting a new chunk for allocation:

```
   if(free_chunks.size() > 0)
   {
    char* c = free_chunks.back();
    free_chunks.pop_back();
    return c;
   }
   else{ // Error, not enough memory... }
```

Returning a chunk after deallocation:

```
free_chunks.push_back(c);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement simple object pool with O(1) object retriving. But your objects need to have imternal pointer to next object.
Inside constructor of pool some precalculating:

```
pool.reserve(capacity); //std::vector<Object*>
for (int i = 0; i < capacity; ++i) {
    pool.push_back(new Object());
}
for (int i = 0; i < capacity-1; ++i) {
    pool[i]->setNext(pool[i+1].get());
}
first_available = pool[0].get(); //variable where you store first free object 
pool[capacity-1]->setNext(NULL);
```

Then `getObject` method is:

```
getObject* getObject()
{
    getObject* obj = first_available;
    first_available = first_available->getNext();
    return obj;
}

void returnObject(Object* obj)
{
    obj->setNext(first_available);
    first_available = obj;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You only have fragmentation for the general memory allocation problem, where blocks of arbitrary length are requested. The issue here is that given this memory layout:

```
@@@@@@---@--@-@@@@
```

(where `@` means in use and `-` means free)

You cannot allocate 4 continuous blocks although there are 6 free blocks in total. So you have to increase the total amount of governed space (if possible).
Also in this general scenario deciding which address to pick is not trivial and has several strategies (first fit, worst fit, etc.) that affect the degree of fragmentation.

In your case the problem is significantly easier as you know that the areas you will want to allocate will always be exactly of the size of some integer `k` (say `k = sizeof(T)`).
This means you will always have perfectly fitting blocks which you organise just as you like. Simply deal with the free space as if it was a linked list and always use the very first item in the list to answer memory allocation requests.

```
@@@---@@@------@@@@@@@@@---@@@ (k=3)
```

Now, if you want to allocate in large blocks to amortise allocations you can keep an extra counter of how many slots are used in one particular block in order to release that block when it's empty (**if** you want to ever shrink your reservoir of slots!).

If you insist on always handing out new memory blocks from the most used block you can do this by using an additional list that indicates which block is fullest. Since you can always only change the number of used slots by one, you can keep that list sorted in `O(1)`, simply by swapping adjacent nodes.

Comment: I'm guessing there is no way this works in O(1) when the objects have different sizes?

Comment: @lezebulon: Not that I know of. Unless you are willing to "round up" in order to save space or have some very specific object sizes. But the general problem always produces fragmentation.